# How to use Flask-Migrate with Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-migrate

Since I moved to Google App Engine I cannot run the Flask-Migrate command `python manage.py db migrate` because I have exceptions regarding some GAE related imports (`No module named google.appengine.ext` for example).

Is there a way to run this, or an alternative, to upgrade my database on GAE?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error?

Comment: what do you mean by "upgrade my database on GAE"?

Comment: I'm using a Cloud SQL 2nd generation. When I modify one model in my code, Flask-Migrate generate the migration code to upgrade the current state of the database to the new one (adding one column, removing another one, etc) That's what I mean by Upgrade

Comment: @Miguel There is no stack trace : I don't know how to run the command via app engine, that's all. I cannot simply do something like `./dev_appserver.py manage.py db migrate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to run it, though it's not as straightforward as you'd might like.

1. You need to [configure your Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client#configure-instance-mysql), add yourself as an authorized user (by entering your ip address) and request to have an IPv4 address. Deal with SSL as appropriate.
2. Using a script:

Replacing `user`, `password`, `instance_id`, `db_name`, and `path` below

```
# migrate_prod.py
DB_MIGRATION_URI = "mysql+mysqldb://user:password@instance_id/db_name?ssl_key=path/client-key.pem&ssl_cert=path/client-cert.pem&&ssl_ca=path/server-ca.pem"

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from models import *   # not needed if migration file is already generated

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = DB_MIGRATION_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

3. Run the script as you would to migrate locally: `python migrate_prod.py db upgrade`, assuming your migration file is already there.
4. Release the IPv4, so that you're not charged for it.

I give much credit to other answers: [how to connect via SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785252/how-to-connect-to-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-a-flask-app) and [run alembic migrations on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391120/run-alembic-migrations-on-google-app-engine/35395267) (of which this is probably a duplicate).

Comment: Are we still charged for keeping the IP address ? I thought it was over with the v2 ?

Comment: It may be, I'm still using v1. [See differences between v1 and v2](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/v1-v2-differences)

Comment: Thank you. Assumes this still works but had to edit it a bit to get it to work for our postgres DB, and not having any hard-coded values and also use our existing DB configuration: https://gist.github.com/jwanglof/0131fc3df8a74250c7a20ec91b9ca179